# How to distribute symmetric key between $n$ entities?

Tags: symmetric, secret-sharing, key-distribution

If there are $n$ servers for broadcasting a symmetric key in such a manner that following holds:

1. No server alone can find the key $K$ alone.
2. Any two servers can pass $k_i$ and $k_j$ such that $K=f(k_i, k_j)$ where $i\neq j$

How can a symmetric key be distributed between $n$ entities?

Comment: Shamir secret sharing?

Comment: Thanks, I believe it will work for my case. I will work on it and get back latter.

Comment: maybe group key exchange will also work